# How to use the ajax Json Web Method with amcharts in asp.net

Tags: json, asp.net-ajax, amcharts

[Demo like this map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfpza.jpg)//This the chart fuctions..I want to pass the the country id to chatdata on map //using the ajax json web method.
**//Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.**

```
    var chart;
    var map;
    var chartData = {};

    chartData.world = [
        { source: "Oil", energy: 3882.1 },
        { source: "Natural Gas", energy: 2653.1 },
        { source: "Coal", energy: 3278.3 },
        { source: "Nuclear", energy: 610.5 },
        { source: "Hydro", energy: 740.3 }];
    chartData.KH = [
       { source: "Oil", energy: 404.6 },
       { source: "Natural Gas", energy: 79.8 },
       { source: "Coal", energy: 1537.4 },
       { source: "Nuclear", energy: 15.9 },
       { source: "Hydro", energy: 139.3 }];
    chartData.CN = [
        { source: "Oil", energy: 842.9 },
        { source: "Natural Gas", energy: 588.7 },
        { source: "Coal", energy: 498 },
        { source: "Nuclear", energy: 190.2 },
        { source: "Hydro", energy: 62.2 }];    

    chartData.MY = [
        { source: "Oil", energy: 124.9 },
        { source: "Natural Gas", energy: 350.7 },
        { source: "Coal", energy: 82.9 },
        { source: "Nuclear", energy: 37 },
        { source: "Hydro", energy: 39.8 }];
    chartData.PH = [
       { source: "Oil", energy: 148.5 },
       { source: "Natural Gas", energy: 46.7 },
       { source: "Coal", energy: 245.8 },
       { source: "Nuclear", energy: 3.8 },
       { source: "Hydro", energy: 24 }];
    chartData.TH = [
        { source: "Oil", energy: 148.5 },
        { source: "Natural Gas", energy: 46.7 },
        { source: "Coal", energy: 245.8 },
        { source: "Nuclear", energy: 3.8 },
        { source: "Hydro", energy: 24 }];

    chartData.ID = [
        { source: "Oil", energy: 197.6 },
        { source: "Natural Gas", energy: 78.7 },
        { source: "Coal", energy: 108.8 },
        { source: "Nuclear", energy: 62.1 },
        { source: "Hydro", energy: 16.7 }];
    chartData.VN = [
     { source: "Oil", energy: 197.6 },
     { source: "Natural Gas", energy: 78.7 },
     { source: "Coal", energy: 108.8 },
     { source: "Nuclear", energy: 62.1 },
     { source: "Hydro", energy: 16.7 }];

    AmCharts.ready(function () {
        // *** CREATE CHART *********************************************************
        // PIE CHART
        chart = new AmCharts.AmPieChart();

        // title of the chart
        chart.addLabel("0", "!20", "World", "center", 16);

        chart.backgroundAlpha = 0.4;
        chart.backgroundColor = "#000000";
        chart.dataProvider = chartData.world;
        chart.titleField = "source";
        chart.valueField = "energy";
        chart.sequencedAnimation = true;
        chart.startEffect = "elastic";
        chart.labelsEnabled = false;
        chart.labelText = "[[title]]";
        chart.startDuration = 2;
        chart.labelRadius = 10;

        // WRITE                                 
        chart.write("chartdiv");

        // *** CREATE MAP ***********************************************************

        var chartData1 = generateChartData();
        alert(chartData1);
        map = new AmCharts.AmMap();
        map.pathToImages = "http://www.ammap.com/lib/images/";
        //map.panEventsEnabled = true; // this line enables pinch-zooming and dragging on touch devices
        var dataProvider = {
            mapVar: AmCharts.maps.worldLow
        };
        map.areasSettings = {
            unlistedAreasColor: "#DDDDDD",
            rollOverOutlineColor: "#FFFFFF",
            rollOverColor: "#CC0000"
        };
        dataProvider.areas = [
            { title: "Cambodia", id: chartData1[0].id, selectable: true },
             //{ title: "Cambodia", id:"KH", selectable: true },
            { title: "China", id: chartData1[1].id, selectable: true },
            { title: "Indonesia", id: chartData1[2].id, selectable: true },
            { title: "Malaysia", id: chartData1[3].id, selectable: true },
            { title: "Philippines", id: chartData1[4].id, selectable: true },
            { title: "Thailand", id: chartData1[5].id, selectable: true },
            { title: "Vietnam", id: chartData1[6].id, selectable: true }
        ];

        map.dataProvider = dataProvider;
        map.write("mapdiv");

        map.addListener("clickMapObject", function (event) {
            if (event.mapObject.id != undefined && chartData[event.mapObject.id] != undefined) {
                chart.dataProvider = chartData[event.mapObject.id];
                chart.clearLabels();
                chart.addLabel("0", "!20", event.mapObject.title, "center", 16);
                chart.validateData();
            }
        });

    });
```

//------this is the fuction im calling ..returning the values-------

---

```
  function generateChartData() {
        debugger;
        var chartData2 = [];
        var chartDataResults = new Array();
             $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: 'varmap.aspx/GetDataonload',
            data: {},
            success: function (response) {
                var aData = response.d;

                for (var i = 0; i < aData.length; i++) {
                 var country = aData[i].costtype; 
                    alert(country);
                        chartDataResults.push({
                            id: country
                                        });
                               }
                return chartDataResults;
            }
        });
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The AJAX requests in jQuery are asynchronous. It means that your `generateChartData()` function finishes before the data is actually loaded and proceeds to create the chart without any data.

You need to start creating the chart in AJAX call `success` handler function:

```
function createChart() {
  debugger;
  var chartData2 = [];
  var chartDataResults = new Array();
  $.ajax( {
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: 'varmap.aspx/GetDataonload',
    data: {},
    success: function( response ) {
      var aData = response.d;

      for ( var i = 0; i < aData.length; i++ ) {
        var country = aData[ i ].costtype;
        alert( country );
        chartDataResults.push( {
          id: country
        } );
      }

      // create the chart here
      // PIE CHART
      chart = new AmCharts.AmPieChart();

      // title of the chart
      chart.addLabel( "0", "!20", "World", "center", 16 );

      chart.backgroundAlpha = 0.4;
      chart.backgroundColor = "#000000";
      chart.dataProvider = chartDataResults;
      chart.titleField = "source";
      chart.valueField = "energy";
      chart.sequencedAnimation = true;
      chart.startEffect = "elastic";
      chart.labelsEnabled = false;
      chart.labelText = "[[title]]";
      chart.startDuration = 2;
      chart.labelRadius = 10;

      // WRITE                                 
      chart.write( "chartdiv" );
    }
  } );
}

$( document ).ready( createChart );
```

Comment: Can you please paste the code in the arrangement in the function..im not getting how to use it..Thnks @martynasma

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: AmCharts.AmPieChart is not a constructor..Tihis error is coming when use this code..Can u please see the  demo link ..like that i want to make Ammap..

Comment: Kindly help me ..i need to make the geochart.@martynasma

Comment: Are you including pie.js?

Comment: <script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/ammap_amcharts_extension.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/maps/js/worldLow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="JSfiles/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: OK, I did provide general guidelines: you create your chart and map if it relies on loaded data in the success handler. I'm can't develop your code for you. You'll need to drive this one home by yourself. Sorry.

Comment: chartDataResults.push( {
                                "map": "worldLow",
                                "areas": [
                                  { "id": "US", "color": "#00CC00" },
                                  { "id": "FR", "color": "#0000CC" }]


                            } );
                        }

Comment: chart = new  AmCharts.maps();
                      
                        //"Type":"Map";
                        // title of the chart
                        chart.addLabel( "0", "!20", "World", "center", 16 );

                        chart.backgroundAlpha = 0.4;
                        chart.backgroundColor = "#000000";
                        chart.dataProvider = chartDataResults;
  chart.write( "chartdiv" );
                    }
                } );

Comment: after this its showing....error:Uncaught TypeError: AmCharts.maps is not a constructor@ martynasma.....I need the help for only ths

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: AmCharts.maps is not a constructor..im facing this error